# How to add Speech-to-Text into a chat application that is written on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, react-native-gifted-chat

My friends and I are working on a project that is a chat application that will implement Speech-To-Text, Text-to-Speech, and Translation APIs of Google. Gifted Chat and Firebase on the chat application. Chat App is working well with Firebase. We added TTS on it and it is also working well but we can't add the STT. We aim that users can use a microphone and the app can convert that speech into text. This text will automatically appear on the text box of the user. We believe that we must manually add STT to Gifted Chats modules but we don't know how to do it. There is also no source on the Internet about that. We will be so happy if anyone can help us. Thank you!

Comment: Could you be more precise at to what did you tried, what failed, why did it failed or logs of the failures, bits of code,...?

Answer (score 1):

Use react-native-voice library for the speech recognition

There is a text and onInputTextChanged prop in Gifted Chat that can help you handle the speech result appearing in the text box.

```
import Voice from '@react-native-community/voice';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { GiftedChat, Composer } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';

const VoiceTest = () => {
  const [speech, setSpeech] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = onSpeechPartialResults;
  
  return () => Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners)
}, [])

  const onSpeechStart = () => {
  ...
  }

  const onSpeechEnd = () => {
  ...
  }

  const onSpeechError = () => {
  ...
  }

  const onSpeechResults = (e) => {
  ...
  setSpeech(e.value[0])
  }

  const onSpeechPartialResults = (e) => {
  ...
  setSpeech(e.value[0])
  }

  const startListening = () => {
  ...
  // You can set the locale to any language you want it to recognize, I am using Nigerian English.
  Voice.start('en-NG')
  }

  const renderComposer = (props) => {
  // Adds a Mic Button in the text box, you can style it as you want
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
     <Composer {...props} />
     <MicrophoneButton onPress={startListening} />
    </View>
   )
  }

  return (
    ...
    <GiftedChat 
      renderComposer={renderComposer}
      text={speech}
      onInputTextChanged={setSpeech} 
     />
    ...
  )
 ...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,i'm trying to search the list of all the locales that it supports, can you guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-voice](https://github.com/react-native-community/voice) library

Here's the example usage:

```
import Voice from '@react-native-community/voice';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class VoiceTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStartHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEndHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResultsHandler.bind(this);
  }
  onStartButtonPress(e){
    Voice.start('en-US');
  }
  ...
}
```